# reading data from a file into an array error in C

Tags: c

I am trying to read from a file specified in a command prompt through terminal using the line `program < file.txt` and then print it again to check it works. I get the error `Segmentation fault: 11`, I'm not sure if my file is opening correctly in my program.

This is the code so far:

```
#define MAX 1000
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    double values[MAX];

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%lf", values);
    printf("%f\n", *values);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either invoke your program with `program file.txt` or read from stdin in your code.

Comment: `fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); fscanf(fp, "%lf", values);` How do you know `fp != NULL`? That's a condition that could cause a segfault (and there don't appear to be other conditions in your code that could). If you're able to duplicate a failure with such a small block of code, you _really_ should try to debug it yourself before asking for help! Not only does it reduce site clutter, but you will learn much more like that and become a better developer as a result.

Comment: use valgrind to know which line raises the segmentation fault.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz Telling someone who is obviously not used to a command line interface to use _valgrind_ or _gdb_ is sort of ironic, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

You should execute your program like

```
./program  file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure if my file is opening correctly in my program

Then you should really test for it, you are getting a segfault because `fopen` is returning `NULL`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    double values[MAX];

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("Invalid file name \n");
        return -1;
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%lf", values);
    printf("%f\n", *values);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

`fopen` is `NULL` because you are invoking the program in the wrong manner, `<` and `>` are a re-directions which can be useful but is not what you are trying to do in this case, correct way to invoke it is to simply pass it the arguments directly.

```
./program input.file
```

Comment: Fair answer, and indeed it *will* tell the OP that the file could not be opened. Which would automatically lead to a next question. Better to also add *why* the OP's `program < file.txt` failed.

Comment: @Jongware I was looking for a SO answer going into bash redirections in order to explain what `<` means in this context but seems beyond the scope of the question

Comment: Agreed with that, hence my assessment it would irrevocably lead to a follow-up question: "*why* does it tell me the file cannot be opened *even though* I supply it on the command line?" Your addition *is* useful in this regard.

Comment: By the way: I downvoted the question because the problem is not in the code, but in the OP's misunderstanding of pretty much basic command line operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, either:
1) check the way you're invoking it, i.e,

- check if the 'program' is an executable file, you can make it executable using chmod command in linux
- check if the path to 'program' or 'file.txt' is correct

2) (I'm not sure of this): check if the content of 'file.txt' is of the right content. (I don't think it should affect to the extent that it causes a segmentation fault, but still, check it.)